# setAttribute and change the text

Tags: javascript

How can I set multiple attributes at once with JavaScript?

I have two goals.
1- Change the * sign to # (Done)
2- Set attribute to element but I couldn't

I want it like this

```html
<div attributeForFuture># A</div>
<div><div attributeForFuture># B</div></div>
<div attributeForFuture># AA</div>
<div><div><div attributeForFuture># C</div></div></div>
```

```js
let all = document.querySelectorAll("div");
for (newChanges of all) {
  let r = newChanges.textContent.replace('*', '#');
  newChanges.innerText = r;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>* A</div>
    <div><div>* B</div></div>
    <div>* AA</div>
    <div><div><div>* C</div></div></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For set attribute to element use `setAttribute()` function of javascript.
but for replace you have to reverse sort all element.
So reversing the list of all the elements will change the sub-element first then change the parent

And also use `innerHTML` instead of `innerText` for replace.

```js
let all = document.querySelectorAll("div");

// need to reverse sort otherwise it will set Attribute to parents element.
all = [...all].sort((a, b) => (a > b ? 1 : -1)) 

for (newChanges of all){
  var oldtext = newChanges.innerHTML; // store old text for check if replce or not
  let r = oldtext.replace('*', '#');
  if(oldtext != r){ // replace if it content what you find.
    newChanges.innerHTML = r;
    
    // use can set Attribute as follow.
    newChanges.setAttribute('attributeForFuture', '');
  }
}

console.log(document.querySelectorAll("section")[0].innerHTML)
```

```html
<section>
    <div>* A</div>
    <div><div>* B</div></div>
    <div>* AA</div>
    <div><div><div>* C</div></div></div> 
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `setAttribute()` Funtion

```js
let all = document.querySelectorAll("div");

        for (newChanges of all) {
            let r = newChanges.textContent.replace('*', '#');
            newChanges.innerText = r;
            newChanges.setAttribute('attributeForFuture','');
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>* A</div>
    <div><div>* B</div></div>
    <div>* AA</div>
    <div><div><div>* C</div></div></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method to set attribute value on `element`.

I guess you want to add `attributeForFuture` attribute to `div`. it will be added with `newChanges.setAttribute('attributeForFuture', '');`. Check below code.

```js
let all = document.querySelectorAll("div");

for (newChanges of all) {
  let r = newChanges.textContent.replace('*', '#');
  newChanges.innerText = r;
  
  newChanges.setAttribute('attributeForFuture', '');
}
```

```html
<div>* A</div>
<div>
  <div>* B</div>
</div>
<div>* AA</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>* C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```